# Registration questionnaire to prevent spammers

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, captcha

I want to add some specific General Knowledge question related to users of my targeted area only at the user registration form because of spamming from untargeted users( from across world).
**Is there any module I can use to add question/answer in the registration form?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the [CAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/captcha)/[reCAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) and the [CAPTCHA Riddler](http://drupal.org/project/riddler) if you are looking for this exact use case. With these modules you can choose which forms to display CAPTCHA on and you can create your own custom questions and answers.

Otherwise, like Rimian says, there's [Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom)

Comment: Don't just use plain captcha, always use recapcha. Recaptcha helps the world.

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary for the question to be "General Knowledge"? You only want to determine if the user is human, right? I would use mollom:

http://mollom.com/
http://drupal.org/project/mollom

Comment: no, captcha won't do. I want to prevent "unwanted" humans who are coming only to spam from other regions/countries of the world

Answer (score 2):

If I were to do this, I would create a small module using hook_form_alter working on the registration form, which would add fields for the questions, as well as a verification function to check whether the answers were correct.